# Applying for job at company where you were rejected before?

Tags: software-industry

I am working as a QA (Intermediate Test Analyst) at company in New Zealand. I am looking to change the job these days and I have applied for two companies I really want to join and work with. The problem is I have already applied for both of them before and wasnt successful. I will give u a complete scenario for both the cases so that you are able to guide me better.
1: I applied for this company two years back and got an email from the HR that they have shortlisted the CV and it wasnt one of those automated emails. However, a month after I get an email saying my application was unsuccessful. 
I have applied for this company again now via an internal referral and it been 4 working days and have received an acknowledgement from them that they received my CV but nothing afterwards. Let me tell you this company takes a long time to revert. My question is what are my chances for landing this job or do they reject the candidates straight away if they were un successful earlier.

2: The other one I applied I actually did well on the written test and then I had an interview with the team leader. It was unsuccessful. and now they are looking for candidate matching my profile. And the recruitment agent came up wit this option. however she is reluctant to refer me to this company. should I apply for this role or not. Please Advise
Thanks 
Fez

Answer (score 0):

I currently hold a job at a company where I got approved only on my second time applying. From this fact I can only assume that some employers don't really mind if people re-apply. Maybe some do, but that will depend on company policy and you have no way of knowing. If you want the job, you have nothing to lose by just applying! The most that's going to happen is they are going to ask you if you've been there before (they might not even remember), and you can prepare an answer for that.

Also, remember, the last time you applied for both of these companies it is likely that *someone* got approved for the role. It wasn't you, but whoever it was he's not there to take the role away from you this time!

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you were shortlisted you were seen as meeting some of the requirements for the offer of a position. If you *know* why they eventually hired someone else, then you might have a way to discriminate whether it's possible to be successful or not.

If they eventually hired the other person because they were slightly more suited for the position, were willing to accept a bit less pay, or because they interviewed a bit better, then you should have a good chance. If they hired the other person because they discovered your resume was full of lies, including omission of your lengthy jail term for workplace violence and sexual harassment, then you would likely be wasting your time applying.

Chances are your situation is much closer to the first situation and you're not wasting your time. Unless you know of a good reason not to re-apply, I don't see much downside. An internal recommendation can be a powerful thing to have on your side.